# Произведение чисел в двоичной СС на C++

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

Всем привет!)
Есть очень странное задание... Надо на C++ написать программу,которая производила умножение двух двоичных чисел (любых по разряду). проблема программы в чем... Нужно что бы умножение происходило в двоичной СС. Способ перевод в десятичную систему там умножение и обратный перевод не подходит...
У кого нибудь есть идеи как это можно реализовать? И по возможности код,который был бы понятен новичку...

Comment: Ну, начните с перевода в двоичную систему. Вам понятно, как это сделать?

Comment: Программа такова.... На вход программа получает 2 числа уже в двоичном виде (к примеру 111 и 101)

Comment: Так, ладно. Вы умеете двоичные числа в столбик умножать?

Comment: Да) Но я не понимаю как это сделать в коде)

Comment: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/111118/dFKP0EzL?a К примеру вот) Как написать первые 5 строчек я понимаю)) А как потом правильно сложить нет идей(

Comment: То есть на самом деле вам непонятно, как сложить два двоичных числа? В гугле должны быть примеры...

Comment: Можно сказать и так) Только и нормальных ответов как сложить я не нашел(может быть потому что новичок)))) Ну и вдруг нестандартные решиния предложат))

Comment: Вообще "в компьютере" числа уже хранятся в двоичном виде, и арифметические операции с ними в том же виде производятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define GETBIT(x,pos)   ( ((x) & ( 0x1 << (pos) )) != 0 )

    int a = 15, b = 5, c = 0;
    for (int j = 31; j >= 0; --j)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            tmp = (GETBIT(a, i) & GETBIT(b, j)) == 1 ? ((tmp + 1) << 0x1) : (tmp << 0x1);
        }
        c += (tmp << j);
    }
    std::cout << c * 0.5 << std::endl;
```

Функция GETBIT возвращает значение из логической операции `(выражение) != 0`. В самом выражении возвращается либо значащий бит(именно значащий, то есть число, соответствующее двоичному, в котором единица стоит в какой-либо позиции), либо 0. Все потому что в функцию мы передаем число и искомую позицию бита(хотим узнать стоит там 0 или 1). Чтобы возвращать только 1/0 - проводим лог.операцию(так сказать нормализацию).
Далее, tmp - то что записываем в одну строчку на бумажке, после умножения верхних "битов" на нижний. Нужно заметить, что я начал считать с последнего бита в числе, чтобы сдвиг `tmp << 0x1` происходил правильно. И сразу полученное произведение суммируем с окончательным числом(c), также со сдвигом(ведь при умножении, каждую новую "строчку" мы начинаем со сдвигом влево.
Также объясню, окончательный результат делю на 2, так как был лишний сдвиг в цикле(лишнее умножение на 2).